# How can I take a screenshot of a table using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer

I'm trying to use **Puppeteer** to take screenshot of commodities and stock prices, the website is [this one](https://www.canalrural.com.br/cotacao/soja/). The class I wanna take a screenshot is the `.trigo` one, but I wanna remove the `.abas` before. The only way that I could make it works was doing like this:

```
await page.goto('https://www.canalrural.com.br/cotacao/soja/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
await page.setViewport({width: 800, height: 1640});
await page.$eval('div.trigo > div > div:nth-child(3) > h3', (el) => el.scrollIntoView());
await page.screenshot({
    path: folder + '02 - soja.jpg',
    type: 'jpeg',
    quality: 70
});
```

But even the height of the Viewport change every time I check it (because they input new information in the tables)... What is the best way to get the `.trigo` class content, remove the `.abas` class and take the screenshot? Thank you guys.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64226550/puppeteer-delete-an-element-for-a-screenshot/73312572#73312572) to a similar question offers a slightly-different approach worth considering in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the element using an `evaluate` expression.

```
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementById("abas").remove());
```

And then you can get the element `.trigo` and call `screenshot` on that element.

```
var el = await page.$('.trigo');
await el.screenshot({
    path: folder + '02 - soja.jpg',
    type: 'jpeg',
    quality: 70
});
```

Comment: ```(node:4756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: el.screenshot is not a function```

With the code:

```await page.goto('https://www.canalrural.com.br/cotacao/mercado_financeiro/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName("abas")[0].remove());
var el = page.$('.algodao');

await el.screenshot({
    path: folder + '00 - dolar.jpg',
    type: 'jpeg',
    quality: 70
});```

Comment: I forgot the await in page.$

Comment: A M A Z I N G
THank you @hardkoded