# puppeteer delete an Element for a screenshot

Tags: html, node.js, dom, puppeteer

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a page but the cookies pages get in front of because of some scripts (My software should go on any website so I can't provide the HTML).

The things is the delete in puppeteer is not working and I need some help with that.

```
            await this.sleep(5 * 1000);
            let body = await browserPage.evaluate(() => {
                document.querySelectorAll('#didomi-popup')[0].outerHTML = "";
                return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
            });
            await browserPage.screenshot({path: "test.jpg", fullPage: true});
```

So Yes didomi-popup exist I even try  `document.querySelectorAll('#didomi-popup')[0].outerHTML = "";` on the console of chrome and it delete the element.
The waiting seem also good because the cookies's popup is in the body that page.evaluate return.

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trying other things I constat that the popup keeps gettings back on the screenshot and so I delete also all script in Javascript to prevent it and now it works

This code delete the popup and the script and then it setup the webpage with no script and so the page is static now for the screenshot.

```
            let body = await browserPage.evaluate(() => {
                const deleteElement = function(selector) {for (let i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {selector[i].outerHTML = "";}} 
                const elemToDelete = ["#didomi-popup", "script"];
                for (let i = 0; i < elemToDelete.length; i++) {
                    deleteElement(document.querySelectorAll(elemToDelete[i]))
                }
                return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
            });
            await browserPage.setContent(body)
            await browserPage.screenshot({path: path, fullPage: true});
```

I know for other people deleteing script can be an issue but I wait a 7 seconds before the eval and so I just want to take a picture of the webpage without doing any interraction with it so it works pretty well for me !

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
await page.goto('<url_here>');

let div_selector_to_remove= ".xj7.Kwh5n";
await page.evaluate((sel) => {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
    for(var i=0; i< elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
    }
}, div_selector_to_remove)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach might be to use the [`element.screenshot({ ... })`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.elementhandle.screenshot/) API.

The idea here is to isolate the element you want to screenshot from the entire page, not just delete annoying elements blocking your screenshot.

```
browserPage.$('.my-css-class')
    .then(element => {
        if (element) { 
            return element.screenshot({}); 
        }

        // default to page
        page.screenshot({});
    });
```

For additional reading, check out [Bannerbear's blog post](https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-take-screenshots-with-puppeteer/#taking-a-screenshot-of-a-particular-html-element).